# Printing a file in columns with arbitrary amount of rows

Tags: bash, columns, printf, pr

I have this file:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
```

And I want to print it across 3 columns with this structure so that first column has lines `1-2-3`, second column has the lines `4-5` and the last column has the lines `6-7-8-9` (or the rest of the file):

```
line1 line4 line6
line2 line5 line7
line3       line8
            line9
```

Essentially I want to print a file in a way that the output is distributed to *N* columns and every column has predetermined (and possibly different from each other) amount of lines. If possible, I want to preserve leading/trailing spaces in lines. How can I do that?

I fiddled around with `columns` and `pr`, but I couldn't even come close.

Comment: Something like this could work: `pr -m <(sed -n 1,3p file) <(sed -n 4,5p file) <(sed -n 6,9p file)`

Comment: That solves my problem, thanks! Maybe add as an answer so I can accept it? (And can you explain how it works?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `merge` functionality of `pr`, which merges multiple files to columns.

Something like this would work:

```
pr -J -m <(sed -n 1,3p file) <(sed -n 4,5p file) <(sed -n 6,9p file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using `paste`:

```
paste <(sed '1,3!d' infile) <(sed '4,5!d' infile) <(sed '6,$!d' infile)
```